# C program help to open a file in Unix/Linux using getopt and command line argument

Tags: c, linux, unix, command-line, arguments

I am trying to work on my college assignment that required programming in C in Unix. I have to take command line arguments and open a file with the name passed as an argument. I've been trying to find help, but couldn't find any resources to help me understand how to parse the argument as a string and open the required file. I'm seeking examples or links that point me in the right direction.

I'm including the short piece of code where I'm trying to parse the options using getopt(). What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>


int main(int argc[], char *argv[])
{
        int option;
        while(option = getopt(argc, argv, "hi:o:") != -1)
        {
                switch (option){
                        case 'h':
                                printf("Usage : -i [input file name]\n-o [output file name]");
                                break;
                        case 'i':
                                printf("\n Input file is: %s",argv[1]);
                                break;
                        case 'o':
                                printf("\n Output file is: %s",argv[2]);
                                break;
                }
        }

return 0;
}
```

I keep getting "Unrecognized command line option error". Also, when I try to include a text file, I believe that the error says that the option is being parsed as an int, but the argument is a string.

P.S: I'm not really looking get any direct answers here. I want the community to help me learn in the best possible way.

Comment: If you're going to use `getopt`, you shouldn't be using `argv` directly in your `switch` block. Instead, you should be using `optarg`.

Comment: You should also explicitly show the command you are entering.

Comment: @MikeHolt What do you mean by that? I'm sorry I didn't understand.

Comment: @PManojMJ If you find any answer helpful ( answered your question ) it is customary here on StackOverflow to accept the answer or upvote it.

Comment: @Chimera I'm sorry. I was busy doing my work. I did it now. Thank you for reminding me. Keep it up man. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should be using `optarg`. Here is an example that is pretty comprehensive:

```
/*
    example of command line parsing via getopt
    usage: getopt [-dmp] -f fname [-s sname] name [name ...]

    Paul Krzyzanowski
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int debug = 0;

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    extern char *optarg;
    extern int optind;
    int c, err = 0; 
    int mflag=0, pflag=0, fflag=0;
    char *sname = "default_sname", *fname;
    static char usage[] = "usage: %s [-dmp] -f fname [-s sname] name [name ...]\n";

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "df:mps:")) != -1)
        switch (c) {
        case 'd':
            debug = 1;
            break;
        case 'm':
            mflag = 1;
            break;
        case 'p':
            pflag = 1;
            break;
        case 'f':
            fflag = 1;
            fname = optarg;
            break;
        case 's':
            sname = optarg;
            break;
        case '?':
            err = 1;
            break;
        }
    if (fflag == 0) {   /* -f was mandatory */
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: missing -f option\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, usage, argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    } else if ((optind+1) > argc) { 
        /* need at least one argument (change +1 to +2 for two, etc. as needeed) */

        printf("optind = %d, argc=%d\n", optind, argc);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: missing name\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, usage, argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    } else if (err) {
        fprintf(stderr, usage, argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    /* see what we have */
    printf("debug = %d\n", debug);
    printf("pflag = %d\n", pflag);
    printf("mflag = %d\n", mflag);
    printf("fname = \"%s\"\n", fname);
    printf("sname = \"%s\"\n", sname);

    if (optind < argc)  /* these are the arguments after the command-line options */
        for (; optind < argc; optind++)
            printf("argument: \"%s\"\n", argv[optind]);
    else {
        printf("no arguments left to process\n");
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

This example and more information is found [here](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/c-tutorials/getopt.html).

Comment: Thanks for the resource. I'll go through it and will post an update.